# Add Custom catalog_product_link_type Into database [Related Products, Up-Sells, Cross-Sells Section] Product Add

Tags: magento2, custom, related-products

I Am Creating Custom catalog_product_link_type,

I've added Additional Section in Related Products Section And It is Working.

But How to Save Values Of This additional section Into Database.
[image]

I have Created My Custom type by adding it into catalog_product_link_type table.

Does AnyOne Know which controller, js, event is used for saving this data.??

Comment: There is a sample module here: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_ProductRelation

Comment: @ Khoa TruongDinh Custome Type is Not Saving In this Module...

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh my magento version is 2.1.5

Comment: I will check later. I think many users can use that module, so it will work for you as well. But, I don't know why it doesn't work for your Magento version. Can you check with the 2.1.9 version?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh yes, i'll check and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Some R&D I came To This Solution.

Creating Preference For **Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper" type="Your\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper"/>
```

OverRide **setProductLinks()**  Of That Class Like This,

```
    protected function setProductLinks(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $links = $this->getLinkResolver()->getLinks();

        $product->setProductLinks([]);

        $product = $this->productLinks->initializeLinks($product, $links);
        $productLinks = $product->getProductLinks();
        $linkTypes = [
            'related' => $product->getRelatedReadonly(),
            'upsell' => $product->getUpsellReadonly(),
            'crosssell' => $product->getCrosssellReadonly(),
            'yourtype' => $product->getYourTypeReadonly()
        ];

        foreach ($linkTypes as $linkType => $readonly) {
            if (isset($links[$linkType]) && !$readonly) {
                foreach ((array) $links[$linkType] as $linkData) {
                    if (empty($linkData['id'])) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $linkProduct = $this->getProductRepository()->getById($linkData['id']);
                    $link = $this->getProductLinkFactory()->create();
                    $link->setSku($product->getSku())
                        ->setLinkedProductSku($linkProduct->getSku())
                        ->setLinkType($linkType)
                        ->setPosition(isset($linkData['position']) ? (int)$linkData['position'] : 0);
                    $productLinks[] = $link;
                }
            }
        }

        return $product->setProductLinks($productLinks);
    }
```

After That Data Will Be saved In **catalog_product_link** And Other Related Tables.